# make an action with ajax when i click on anchor

Tags: ajax, anchor

i try to found a code enable to do something like this :

my link look like this :

```html
<li><a href="#newgame" id="linknewgame">Jouer</a></li>
```

the destination of this link is  . This article is only available on the page when i click on my link, he will be available by a css  :

```css
#main {
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
  -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
 }

  #main article {
   -moz-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
   transform: translateY(0.25rem);
   -moz-transition: opacity 2.325s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.325s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2.325s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.325s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 2.325s ease-in-out, -ms-transform 0.325s ease-in-out;
   transition: opacity 2.325s ease-in-out, transform 0.325s ease-in-out;
   padding: 4.5rem 2.5rem 1.5rem 2.5rem ;
   position: relative;
   width: 90rem;
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(27, 31, 34, 0.85);
   border-radius: 4px;
   opacity: 0;
  }

   #main article.active {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
   }
```

so, i try to load the content of  only when he is visible on the screen. with an ajax or i don't know actually xD

my next code inside this will be something like this :

```js
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/api/pages/newgame",
                        method: "GET",
                        data: "token=3660935154fe3d7e9612466f6e70fbe6",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(json) {
                                console.log(json);
                                $("#response").append("<p><b>Page title: " + json.data.content+"</p>");
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                                console.log("Error");
                        }
                });
        });
        </script>
```

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <li><a href="#newgame" onclick="yourAJAXFunction()" id="linknewgame">Jouer</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
 function yourAJAXFunction(){
  $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost/api/pages/newgame",
       method: "GET",
       data: "token=3660935154fe3d7e9612466f6e70fbe6",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            $("#response").append("<p><b>Page title: " + json.data.content+"</p>");
            },
             error: function(data) {
                 console.log("Error");
             }
    });
 }
```